# C bucket of strings

Tags: c, hashtable, bucket

I have an assignment to complete . It says I have to read a file which contains 3 millions  of strings.
I have to read the file and build a structure to hold the strings. This system must be able to answer the question "is this new string present?"

I AM also expected  to break the **list down into "buckets" of strings so the 'string to match' is able to chose the correct bucket to search in (quickly) and that bucket should contain no more than total/hashMask strings or so (ie 3,000,000 / 0xFFF == 732 objects per bucket).**

Now I have created a structure of hash table, list  and function to read a file , add and delete function. But I have no clue about the text typed in bold. Do I need to imp-lement something (requested in bold) in Hash function?

Below is my sample code

```
 #define MAX_NAME 100 
    /* Linked list structure */
    typedef struct list
    {
        char *string;
        int index;
        struct list *next
    } list_t ;

     /* hash table structure*/

     typedef struct hashTable
    {
        int size; // size of the table
        list_t **table; // the table element
    } hash_table_t;

    HashListType *createHashTable( size_t size)
   {        
     // allocate hash table ..I know how to do it    
   }    
    unsigned int hash(HashListType *hashTable, void *str )     
     {        
        uint64_t hashVal;    
        hashVal = 0;    
       while( *str != '\0')   
       {
         hashVal = *str + (hashVal << 5 ) - hashVal;    
         str++;    
       }     
      return (hashVal % hashTable->size);     
     }      

    void addToHashList( HashListType *list, void *obj, uint64_t hash)    
   {    

      // add item of new list to table  --> have an idea how to do it       
   }       

  void removeFromHashList(HashListType *list, void *criterion, uint64_t hash )      
   {
      // got an idea how to do it       
   }      
   /*        
      this  function will read the file (assume one string per line)     
      and create the list of lists (list of buckets), adding one object per string.    
   */     
     HashList *loadDataSet(char *filename, int hashMask)     
     {     
        // to read a file
       char readString[ MAX_NAME];
       File *fp ;

        if( (fp = fopen(filename, "r") )== NULL)
        {
          printf(" failed to open the file\n");
          exit(0);
        }
        while( fgets ( readString,MAX_NAME -1, fp ) != NULL)
        {
         //need to break the list down into "buckets" of strings so the 'string to match'
         // is able to chose the correct bucket to search in (quickly)
         //and that bucket should contain no more than total/hashMask strings
         or so (ie 3,000,000   / 0xFFF == 732 objects per bucket). 
        }
      fclose(fp);
     }
```

Comment: Try thinking about how you'd solve the problem if you yourself have to do the work. In other words, what would you personally need to do for each string?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you've chosen the incorrect data structure for your hash tables:

```
typedef struct hashTable
{   
  char key[MAX_NAME];
  int index;
  struct hashTable *next;
  struct hashTable *prev;
};
```

One of the primary benefits of a hash table is being able to jump directly to the bucket that contains the element you're searching for. This is part of a *linked list* of hash buckets -- which means you must iterate through an average of 4098/2 buckets on *every lookup or insertion*. That will not provide you with the performance you need.

Your hash table should instead be an array of `structs`; each `struct` should have a pointer to a string (or direct storage for *short strings*) and a pointer to the next `struct` in the bucket. (While this `struct hashTable` could *also* be the in-bucket structure, it is a rare hash table that needs `next` and `prev` links within the buckets. Which is why I guessed this data structure is instead intended for the table itself.)

You also need to select a good [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). There is a ton of research into good hash functions, but you're really looking for something better than horrible for a homework assignment. The input to the hash function is your strings, and the output should be an integer. You'll need to `%` the output with the size of your array (pick a prime near 5000) to figure out which bucket to use.

Here's a hash function from the [`stb.h` library of convenient functions](http://nothings.org/stb/stb_h.html):

```
unsigned int stb_hash(char *str)
{
   unsigned int hash = 0;
   while (*str)
      hash = (hash << 7) + (hash >> 25) + *str++;
   return hash + (hash >> 16);
}
```

A short hint that while the `stb.h` code is in the public domain, it would be very wise to reference the source in the program -- professors, lawyers, and in the future, your co-workers, will thank you for including the source of things you didn't do yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A hash function can be defined not only for integer but also for character, or string (hint: character encoding).
Make hash function that for string.
When you submit, must be submitted along with the output file or run.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This answer depends on how strict your assignment text is on using "buckets", as I interpret your question a bit more liberal than your example code.*

The undoubtedly best data structure for this task is a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or a generalisation of it. You can build a tree where each node contains "tiny" hash tables that store one *atom* of the strings. For instance, atoms of your string could be single characters. You can parametrise your data structure to change the size of an atom (i.e. each node has a fixed array of 16 sub-tries, so that your atoms are 4 bits long) -- this array approach allows for constant time descent but requires a comparatively large about of memory. But as I said, instead of fast lookup-arrays you can use tiny hash tables (which would be more compatible to your assignment).